# How is it decided, what granularity will be used for top ranking percentage in profile?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious, because for me, it is showing top 2% monthly, even though my weekly ranking is better than that. Is there some kind of a scoring function which says that 2% monthly is better than 1% weekly? Thanks

Comment: I've seen it referenced and it has a lot to do with the overall rank.  If there were more active users in the month, the 2% monthly could be considered much better than the 1% weekly.  I'm looking for it now